# Appending lists and comparison inside of a object

Tags: python

Hey guys im trying to create a small scenario in a art café. My plan is that in the empty canvas list, as more canvases are added the list gets filled with the respective canvas, however when a certain number of canvases are reached (in this case 3), a message will appear that there are no more canvases left. I could not think of how to deduce this in my code and I'd very much be happy to hear everyone's suggestions (this is my first time using stack overflow and am excited to be part of the community!)

```
primary_colors = ['blue','red','yellow']   

def lists(a):
    print('these are the colors you can choose:')
    for x in a:
        print(x)

lists(primary_colors)

class canvas():
    canvases = []

class colors(canvas):
def __init__(self,color,canvas,type_of_color,):
    self.canvases.append(canvas)
    print(f"So you'd like to use {color} and {canvas}? We will get that right away!")

first_painter = colors(primary_colors[1],'white canvas',primary_colors)
```

Comment: You need a `add_canvas` function that has error handling in it instead of appending directly

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: Just put an `if` statement before `self.canvases.append(canvas)` and report the error.

Answer (score 0):

you could probably just say something like

```
canvas = ["canvas1", "canvas2", 3]

if canvas[2] == str(canvas[2]):
    print("occupied")
```

You could replace "str" with "float" or "int" depending on if you want the canvases to be stored as strings, ints or floats. My code basically just checks if the third item in the list is occupied by a string, and if it is the code will print "occupied", if canvas[2] is an int or a float it will not print anything // hence it is not occupied.
If there is no third item in the list and IndexError will occur, this can be fixed by doing this:

```
canvas = ["canvas1", "canvas2"]

try:
    if canvas[2] == int(canvas[2]):
        print("occupied")

except IndexError:
    pass
```

Comment: wrote this super quickly and I gotta head to sleep, but I will answer questions tomorrow, please don't be too harsh (wrote it in less than a minute :))